# Pyspark - Replace 2 or more consecutive words with first word in pysaprk

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with more than 10000 rows. I want to replace the consecutive words with first occurance word. I want this to be done in pyspark.

Here is the pyspark table with list of words. Each list of words is related to each date.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| event_dt   | words                                                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 09/02/2020 |[cell cell option option phone phone talk talk pay pay       ...] |
| 09/05/2020 |[understand understand capable capable optimizing optimizing,...] |
```

and more rows.

The result I want to look like is below with words, string type in each row.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| event_dt   | words                                                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 09/02/2020 |cell option phone talk pay  ... (continues from above table)    |
| 09/05/2020 |understand capable optimizing paying ... (continues...)         |
```

Comment: is the data type of the original `words` column ArrayType or StringType?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `PySpark` has any better provisions but one simple way I can think of is:

let's say `words[event_dt_1]` represents a Python `list` of all special words for a given date `event_dt_1`.

You can do `set(words[event_dt_1])` which will convert the `list` into a `set` which is a data structure where you cannot have duplicates.

You can then do `list(set(words[event_dt_1]))` to convert the `set` with unique words back to a `list`.